# change position of TikZ node halfway

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I am trying to move the node "H" to one of the two positions shown in red below:

[image]

I am not sure how to position it at 'intermediate' positions such as I am suggesting. How could this be done? Is there a more sensible way of defining the positions of the nodes overall? The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    -,
    every loop/.style={},
    auto,
    node distance = 4cm,
    thick,
    main node/.style={
        circle,
        fill=gray!50,
        draw,
        font=\rmfamily\Large\bfseries,
        minimum size=15mm
    }
]

\node[main node] (W) [] {W};
\node[main node] (Z) [right of=W] {Z};
\node[main node] (q) [above right of=Z] {q};
\node[main node] (g) [below right of=q] {g};
\node[main node] (l) [above left of=W] {l};
\node[main node] (gamma) [below left of=l] {${\gamma}$};
\node[main node] (H) [below left of=W] {H};

  \path[
    every node/.style={
        font=\rmfamily\small,
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1pt
    }
]

(H) edge [loop below] node {} (H)
(H) edge [] node {} (W)
(H) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (Z)
(H) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (l)
(W) edge [loop left] node[right=1mm] {} (W)
(W) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (Z)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (Z)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (W)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (H)
(Z) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (l)
(l) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (gamma)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (gamma)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (g)
(g) edge [loop below] node {} (g)
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\node[main node] (H) [below left of=W] {H};`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest adopting `positioning` library uses which introduced more flexible placement options or convert you diagram into a `matrix` which is very usefull for such regular constructions.

With `positioning` you code could be changed to

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    -,
    every loop/.style={},
    auto,
% node distance = 4cm,
% on grid,
    thick,
    main node/.style={
        circle,
        fill=gray!50,
        draw,
        font=\rmfamily\Large\bfseries,
        minimum size=15mm
    }
]

\node[main node] (W) [] {W};
\node[main node] (l) [above left = of W] {l};
\node[main node] (gamma) [below left = of l] {${\gamma}$};
\node[main node] (H) [above right = of W] {H};
\node[main node] (Z) [below right = of H] {Z};
\node[main node] (q) [above right = of Z] {q};
\node[main node] (g) [below right = of q] {g};

  \path[
    every node/.style={
        font=\rmfamily\small,
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1pt
    }
]

(H) edge [loop above] node {} (H)
(H) edge [] node {} (W)
(H) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (Z)
(H) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (l)
(W) edge [loop left] node[right=1mm] {} (W)
(W) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (Z)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (Z)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (W)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (H)
(Z) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (l)
(l) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (gamma)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (gamma)
(q) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (g)
(g) edge [loop below] node {} (g)
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

*Update*

Following Harish Kumar suggestion a solution with `matrix`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    -,
    every loop/.style={},
    auto,
    thick,
    main node/.style={
        circle,
        fill=gray!50,
        draw,
        font=\rmfamily\Large\bfseries,
        minimum size=15mm
    }
]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes={main node}, row sep=8mm, column sep=4mm]{
& I & & H & & q \\
$\gamma$ & & W & & Z & & g\\
};

\path[
    every node/.style={
        font=\rmfamily\small,
        fill=white,
        inner sep=1pt
    }
]

(A-1-4) edge [loop above] node {} (A-1-4)
(A-1-4) edge [] node {} (A-2-3)
(A-1-4) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (A-2-5)
(A-1-4) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (A-1-2)
 (A-2-3) edge [loop left] node[right=1mm] {}  (A-2-3)
 (A-2-3) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (A-2-5)
(A-1-6) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (A-2-5)
(A-1-6) edge [] node[right=1mm] {}  (A-2-3)
(A-1-6) edge [] node[right=1mm] {}(A-1-4)
(A-2-5) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (A-1-2)
(A-1-2) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (A-2-1)
(A-1-6) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (A-2-1)
(A-1-6) edge [] node[right=1mm] {} (A-2-7)
(A-2-7) edge [loop below] node {} (A-2-7)
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What no `matrix` solution? ;)

Comment: Ah, this is perfect. Thank you very much for your suggestions regarding the positioning library and the matrix approach. I'll look into them.

Comment: @HarishKumar Did it. ;-)

Comment: Very nice. But I can vote only once :)